# Why do we use high resistance wire in potentiometer?

Tags: electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, electronics, electrical-engineering

I was recently learning about potentiometer and , my teacher told thta potentiometer wire has very high resistance , but if potentiometer wire has very high resistance , wont the current skip potentiometer wire and just go through the galvanometer wire as its resistance is low as I is inversely proportioanl to R.

Comment: Can you please add a diagram or an image of the circuit you may be talking about?

Comment: In reading the answers below, you need to be aware that some people use "potentiometer" to mean *variable potential divider* and not the voltage *measuring* circuit that contains a potential divider (a long wire with sliding contact in your case) and a galvanometer. [Perhaps the existence of this other meaning is why someone gave you the downvote!]

Answer (score 2):

Potentiometer wire has high resistance so that by turning the control knob to "add" more wire in series, the measured resistance increases by a convenient amount. If the "pot" were wound instead with copper wire, which has very low resistance, it would take a huge increase in the number of wraps in the pot to get a measurable increase in its resistance.

The other reason that wire-wound pots use high-resistance wire is that these pots often have to carry significant amounts of current, which heats the wire up. So they use wire with a high melting point, which usually also means high electrical resistance.

Comment: Yes i do agree with your answer but using an alloy will defeat the reason of making potentiometer in first place as if we use a high resistance wire , there wont be any possibility that current through galvanometer is 0 as I is inversely proprtional to R

Comment: It does not in fact defeat the purpose of a potentiometer, which is a practical embodiment of a *voltage divider*. If you study the operation of a *voltage divider*, you will understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Potentiometer wire has high resistance relative to what? If it was meant that relative to conducting wires, it must be high then thats because, in a potentiometer you just connect a wire to a voltage source $V$. A low resitance wire provides no load and would drive huge currents without a limiting resistance in the circuit.

> wont the current skip potentiometer wire and just go through the galvanometer wire as its resistance is low

The potentiometer is operated near null point - when the galvanometer current is zero. So, for two potentiometers with equal voltage gradients, but differing wire  resistance, the null-point would still be same - i.e the operation won't be affected. Yet the one with higher resistance would warm, warp and waste less.

To drive the point home, since the potential appearing across the galvanometer branch is same, the current through it, determined only by its internal resistance, would also be same. So what is the effect of an increased resistance? The current in the wire decreases, by the same logic. Where has this difference in current gone? Nowhere - the overall current in the circuit has decreased.

There is another reason that a higher resistance per unit length helps. Often while searching for the null-point the probe may touch other points. At such points a current runs through the galvanometer. Here a  higher wire resistance means lower current through the galvanometer for the same length. Since galvs. have tiny max. currents, that is healthier.

Comment: Last time I used a potentiometer (a very long time ago) the slide wire had a resistance of about 10 ohm and the pd across it was supplied by a 2.0 V lead-acid battery! For galvanometer protection I used a 1 k ohm resistor in series with the galvanometer itself, rather than relying on the resistance of the slide-wire for protection. The protection resistor could be shorted out by a switch connected across it, when near the balance point.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the load that you are running on the potentiometer... If you are running like a DC motor with high current rating then you need a low resistance potentiometer... If you need to run a small electronic circuit whose Ampere rating is in mA then you will require high resistance potentiometer... Voltage wise both will give the same output...